# Is there a way to connect a wordpress connection with a mysql workbench remote database connection?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a remote connection to an installs database on wp engine, i'm trying to create a local connection to that database. I can't simply put in the IP address in wp-config as this makes for 30 - 40 + loading times for my local environment.

After discussing with wp engine I was told to use MySQL workbench to make connections, which i've done and the connections made, I just don't know how to make the connection link with wp-config?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: actually configuring in `wp-config` is your best options, this approach is slower due to the fact you will need to connect to a remote entity and network latency on your internet is bad enough to make your wp slower.. or you may go into [mirroring](https://serverfault.com/a/566002/321311) feast which will give you a local copy of the remote database, but again, this might render your db slow.

Comment: You have to check "IP Address Whitelisting" to  remote database connection.